# Trying to handle InstantiationException in JAVA, compiler throws it instead

Tags: java, exception, interface, try-catch, finally

So I'm new at Java, and I'm trying to work with the try, catch and finally features. As my limited understanding goes, a try-catch block allows me to handle exceptions instead of the compiler throwing an error that I can't return to execution from. Is this right? Also, my program doesn't seem to be working, as the compiler throws "Extracur is abstract, cannot be instantiated!" during compilation. How do I get it to display my error message (and execute my finally block) instead?

```
try {
        extracur student1 = new extracur();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("\n Did you just try to create an object for an interface? Tsk tsk.");
    } finally {
        ReportCard student = new ReportCard("Progress Report for the year 2012-13");
        student.printReportCard();
    }
```

PS- extracur is an interface.

Comment: try/catch block are there to capture runtime exceptions - to run a program, you need to compile it - compile errors need to be fixed for the program to be compilable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interfaces can never be directly instantiated.

```
extracur student1=new extracur(); // not possible
```

And you should capitalize interface names. You need instead:

```
Extracur student1 = new Extracur() {
  // implement your methods
};
```

Explanation: The code does not instantiate the interface, but an anonymous inner class which implements the interface.

You should also understand that the compiler throws an error at compile time while you are trying to catch an error at runtime (too late in this case).

Comment: Will do, thanks! I've always wondered though, why is everyone big on camel-case and capitalization in Java? No one insisted on it when I learnt C and C++. Any particular reason?

Comment: This is a common naming convention in Java to capitalize class and interface names while starting variable and method names always with a small letter. It promotes readability and understandability.

Answer (score 0):

Interface cannot be instantiated.It will cause compile error.If you want a test .Try this:

```
 try {
            extracur student1 = new stud();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("\n Did you just try to create an object for an interface? Tsk tsk.");
        } finally {

        }
```

This is a class that impements interface extracur

```
class stud implements extracur{
    public stud()throws InstantiationException{
        throw new  InstantiationException();
    }
}
```